# Firebase/Angular2 - Find lat/long in database that is closest to users lat/long

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a table called `locations` with a set of places and their `lat`/`long`'s.

I'm also using `geolocation` to get the users `lat`/`long`.

What I would like to do is get the `location` that is closest to the user, and check if they are within 5 miles of that place.

I'm not too concerned right now about if the user is within 5 miles, I found an algorithm that seems to do that for me..

But what I am curious about is how I should loop through the firebase table and check if the `lat`/`long` is the closest.. Is there a way with firebase to sort based off of closest to a variable?

The table looks like this (ignore the index, I will change this later with unique ids):

[image]

as well as in javascript:

`user.Lat = 35.90491`

`user.Long = -79.04691`

Any help for matching the user `lat`/`long` with the location `lat`/`long`

I have about 30-40 locations so far in the table.. Planning on adding more.

Thanks!

Comment: considered https://github.com/firebase/geofire?

Comment: @TomaszBubała yes, but I'm unsure of if it's what I really need.. like couldn't I just fetch all the locations and compare the user location vs the data location?

Comment: You could of course. It just might not be effective with many records. I don't know how geofire handles it - I'd check if it offers better solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you talking about small numbers of records (not millions). You can create temporary table or temporary column with following formula:
for each location p -> `(user.lat-p.lat)^2+(user.lon-p.lon)^2`

Then sort it by calculated field - smallest number is closest points.

Keep in mind, that it will work on relatively short distances, but may be wrong when location is too far or close to poles (because of projections).